# android - Canvas draw path on canvas without touch direction

Tags: java, android, canvas

I build this class to draw on screen to implement some brushes created via differents Paints and paths.

Currently is drawing a square based on user touch movement, but the draw path is being rotated by the draw direction of the touch. I tried to apply a rect without no luck and I don't found any related info about this phenom

**EDIT :**
[This image is from current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MPjj.jpg)

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

public class RachetBasic extends androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView {
    private Canvas canvas;
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private Paint bitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);

    private Path squarePath = new Path();
    private Paint squarePaint = new Paint();

    public RachetBasic(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public RachetBasic(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public RachetBasic(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int width, int height, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(width, height, oldw, oldh);

        squarePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        squarePaint.setDither(true);

        squarePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

        squarePaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.SQUARE);
        squarePaint.setStrokeWidth(80);

        squarePaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);

        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmapPaint);

        canvas.drawPath(squarePath, squarePaint);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            squarePath.moveTo(x, y);
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            squarePath.lineTo(x, y);
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            squarePath.lineTo(x, y);

            canvas.drawPath(squarePath, squarePaint);

            squarePath.reset();
        }

        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}
```

```
public class MainActivity extends androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity {
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       setContentView(new RachetBasic(MainActivity.this));
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not really clear what the issue is. Are you trying to draw only a rectangle? Kind of like a resizable selection area? AFAICT, the given code is just drawing the "line" following the touch. Is that the problem? Could you possibly provide some images that show what you're currently getting, and what you're trying to do?

Comment: @MikeM. I put a image of current result. The square is rotated followed by the touch direction, and the intention is that always be drawed like a square ◼

Comment: Ah, OK, I think I see what you mean. In that case, you probably don't want to draw that `Path`, but rather do `drawRect()` calls centered on the touch points, with dimensions of the current stroke width; e.g., `drawRect(x - 40, y - 40, x + 40, y + 40, squarePaint)`. You'll probably also want to set the paint style to `FILL_AND_STROKE`.

Comment: But with this method every touch move will draw a square on top of each other and with alpha color this cant do @MikeM.

Comment: Yeah, with an alpha, that's not going to work. I only suggested it because your code is using a solid color, and I don't think you mentioned an alpha anywhere. I'll have to think about it...

Comment: Yes I forgot to apply the alpha in the example :( Sorry @MikeM. and thanks to help I appreciate it

Comment: Hey, sorry, I forgot to get back to you on this. I'm kinda stumped, honestly. I tried a couple of different things, but I just couldn't get it smooth. I thought of another approach earlier today, and I'll do some testing later on, but I'm not very hopeful. I will let you know if I come up with an acceptable solution.